# hibernate lazy fetch not work properly

Tags: hibernate, fetch, lazy-evaluation

I am using hibernate,with play framework 1.2.4.
Assume that I have a model named Person and a model named IdentityInfo, and the relation is that a person can have only one identity info.
And I want to use lazy fetch on the IdentityInfo fetching.Here is my Model code:

```
public class Person {
    // ... some code

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name = "info_id_fk")
    private IdentityInfo info = null;

    public IndentityInfo getInfo(){
        return this.info;
    }

    public void setInfo(IdentityInfo  info){
        this.info = info;
    }
}

public class IdentityInfo {
  // ... some code
  public String xxx = null;

  public String getXxx(){
      return this.xxx;
  }

  public void setXxx(String xxx){
      this.xxx = xxx;
  }


}
```

But Here is the problem(quite strange):
I have a list of person and i need to go through all person objects' identity info.
And some person object's identity CANT be loaded properly(**person has a Corresponding identityInfo**).
MORE specific,
When i use **java reflect** to get the person's identity info,sometimes the info's attribute is null(but it was not).

But when i simply use `person.info.getXxx()`,the attribute's value came up.

**AND it didn't have any error messages.the program went normally.**

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: please provide exact error messages and/or stack trace

Comment: there are not error messages.the program went normally.

Comment: So the getInfo returned null? Are you sure the DB contained a IdentityInfo corresponding to that Person's info_id_fk? If there is none, then it's normal that the getInfo would return null without error.

Comment: yes.the person has a identityinfo_id_fk and the DB contained a corresponding IdentityInfo.

Comment: Try to increase the logging like so:  log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug  This should give hints, if not please post the logging of a failed lazy fetch and one of a successful fetch

Comment: @Marks can u kindly edit your question "person can have only on identity info." to "person can have only onE identity info." ?

Comment: @Marks can you share your getter and setter method of person model?

Comment: @BalajiReddy i just updated the post. the getter and setter is simple and normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How come setter method has no parameter?

try this

```
    public void setInfo(IndentityInfo info)
      {

       Hibernate.initialize(info);     
       this.info = info;

      }
```

Comment: It turned out the problem occured because in Hibernate,you should use Getter to get attributes so hibernate would really load data and initialize the object.